# Highcharts click event should apply only on marker point

Tags: javascript, highcharts

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {

  title: {
    //text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    text: false
  },

  subtitle: {
    //text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    text: false
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: '$'
    }
    //,categories: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Units'
    },
    categories: [10, 20, 30]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 20,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 0
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true
  },

  /*plotOptions: {
      series: {
          pointStart: 0
      }
  },*/

  series: [{
    lineWidth: 0,
    showInLegend: false,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          hs.close();
          hs.htmlExpand(null, {

            pageOrigin: {
              x: (e.pageX || e.clientX) - 100,
              y: (e.pageY || e.clientY) + 60
            },
            headingText: this.series.name,
            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
              this.y + ' visits',
            width: 200
          });
        }
      }
    },
    states: {
      hover: {
        lineWidthPlus: 0
      }
    },
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [12, 40, 42]
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/css/highslide.css" />

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Lqaxgspe/6/)

As per requirement, I have implemented highslide popup. But in some cases, the toggle click event is applying to the outside of the marker points also. the highslide popup should toggle when I click on marker points only. can anyone help me out with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add chart type `scatter` by default it is type `line`. In `line` chart hover is due to connecting line, which cause pop up to appear.In `scatter` chart this does not happen

```js
Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: "scatter"
  },
  title: {
    //text: 'Solar Employment Growth by Sector, 2010-2016'
    text: false
  },

  subtitle: {
    //text: 'Source: thesolarfoundation.com'
    text: false
  },

  yAxis: {
    title: {
      text: '$'
    }
    //,categories: [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80,90,100]
  },
  xAxis: {
    title: {
      text: 'Units'
    },
    categories: [10, 20, 30]
  },

  legend: {
    align: 'left',
    verticalAlign: 'top',
    y: 20,
    floating: true,
    borderWidth: 0
  },

  tooltip: {
    shared: true,
    crosshairs: true
  },

  /*plotOptions: {
      series: {
          pointStart: 0
      }
  },*/

  series: [{
    lineWidth: 0,
    showInLegend: false,
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function(e) {
          hs.close();
          hs.htmlExpand(null, {

            pageOrigin: {
              x: (e.pageX || e.clientX) - 100,
              y: (e.pageY || e.clientY) + 60
            },
            headingText: this.series.name,
            maincontentText: Highcharts.dateFormat('%A, %b %e, %Y', this.x) + ':<br/> ' +
              this.y + ' visits',
            width: 200
          });
        }
      }
    },
    states: {
      hover: {
        lineWidthPlus: 0
      }
    },
    name: 'Installation',
    data: [12, 40, 42]
  }]

});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>


<!-- Additional files for the Highslide popup effect -->
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide-full.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/js/highslide.config.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.highcharts.com/media/com_demo/css/highslide.css" />

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you.
and when I click on the same marker point the highslide popup should be toggle[show - hide - show]. can you help me out with this issue also?

Comment: Hi, code inside point click logic see `hs.close();` is causing  hide show.

Comment: Hi, it was working fine. but the problem coming when I click on the same marker it is hiding after that again it is opening. it shouldn't happen like that. if the already highslide popup is opened again if I click on the same marker point it should hide and never open it again until I will click it again. But it is working fine only when I click different marker point. I have added those code also in the js fiddle which I have mentioned here. help me to solve this issue.